# Spring MVC: How to remove session attribute?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3

Example of using `@SessionAttributes` below. How to clear `user` session attribute after wizard finished ? In my example after returning to `/wizard0` session attribute still exists. I've tried `status.setComplete()` and `session.removeAttribute("user")` but it doesn't work.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserWizard {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/wizard0", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page1(Model model) {
        if(!model.containsAttribute("user")) {
            model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        }
        return "wizard/page1";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/wizard1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page2(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        user.setFirstname(Utils.randomString());
        return "wizard/page2";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/wizard2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page3(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        user.setLastname(Utils.randomString());
        return "wizard/page3";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/finish", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page4(@ModelAttribute User user, HttpSession session, SessionStatus status) {
        /**
         * store User ...
         */
        status.setComplete();
        session.removeAttribute("user");
        return "redirect:/home";
    }

}
```

### **EDIT**

My mistake. `status.setComplete();` works good. `session.removeAttribute("user")` is nothing to do here.

Comment: `status.setComplete();` supposed to clean up your `SessionAttribute`. Maybe you are setting the user in another class or it's some problem with your session configuration...

Comment: have u confirmed that the session contains the same user object that you added? check the hashcode of user object after and before removing it frm session

Comment: **Sorry. My mistake**. `status.setComplete()` works good however. I have finish button not mapped correctly - method `page4` wasn't called at all, so that was a problem. I saw that `session.removeAttribute("user") / HttpSession` has nothing to do with `@SessionAttributes`. Question to close/delete/etc... Sorry once again.

Answer (score 14):

Try to use `WebRequest.removeAttribute` method instead of `HttpSession.setAttribute` method (example 1). Or another way which do exactly the same you can use 'SessionAttributeStore.cleanupAttribute' (example 2).

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/finish", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String page4(@ModelAttribute User user, WebRequest request, SessionStatus status) {
    /**
     * store User ...
     */
    status.setComplete();
    request.removeAttribute("user", WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/finish", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String page4(@ModelAttribute User user, WebRequest request, SessionAttributeStore store, SessionStatus status) {
    /**
     * store User ...
     */
    status.setComplete();
    store.cleanupAttribute(request, "user");
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

Comment: How to instantiate **SessionAttributeStore** because I have expectation: `Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionAttributeStore]: Specified class is an interface`.

Comment: How to clean up all session attributes in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/finish", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String page4(HttpSession httpsession, SessionStatus status) {

/*Mark the current handler's session processing as complete, allowing for cleanup of 
  session attributes.*/
status.setComplete();

/* Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects boundto it. */
httpsession.invalidate();
return "redirect:/home";
}
```