# Retrieving multiple model attributes from jsp page (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In ReservationController.java I have the following method, which gets a reservation object from new-reservation.jsp

```
@PostMapping("/addBookToReservation")
public String addBookToReservation(Model model,
                                  @Valid @ModelAttribute("reservation") Reservation reservation,
                                  BindingResult result,
                                  RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "reservation/new-reservation";
    }

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("reservation", reservation);
    
    return "redirect:/book/add-book";
}
```

and sends it to BookController.java, where another method adds another attribute to the model

```
@GetMapping("/book/add-book")
public String showAddBookForm(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
    Reservation reservation = (Reservation) model.getAttribute("reservation");
    System.out.println(reservation);       //prints the object I passed it!

    return "/book/add-book";
}
```

and returns the following add-book.jsp

```
<form:form action="/addBook" modelAttribute="book" method="post">                    
   <div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="title">Title</form:label>
            <form:input type="text" id="title" path="title" />
            <form:errors path="title" />
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add book">
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Now, when I handle the form's action addBook

```
@PostMapping("/addBook")
public String addBook(@Valid @ModelAttribute Book book,
                        BindingResult result,
                        Model model) {
    
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "book/add-book";
    }
    
    Reservation reservation = (Reservation) model.getAttribute("reservation");
    System.out.println(reservation); // reservation is null!!
    
    
    return "somewhere/else";
}
```

and I try to retrieve the reservation object from the model I get a null.
How can I pass my reservation object through the JSPs I've showed you before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding @SessionAttributes for the model attribute on top of the controller and [remove the session attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209233/spring-mvc-how-to-remove-session-attribute) when done

```
@SessionAttributes("reservation")
```